# How to make QMainWindow transparent in Qt for Windows 10

Tags: qt

I need my application window (derived from QMainWindow) to be fully transparent. I tried below solution in Linux it works fine.  But in windows I get a black screen instead of transparent screen.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    setStyleSheet("background:transparent;");
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

How can modify this code to work the same transparency in windows too. I am using Windows 10

Comment: try in main.cpp `app.setStyle("Fusion");`

Comment: @MohammadKanan Fusion style is not a transparent.

Comment: See Qt docs: 
`Windows: The widget needs to have the Qt::FramelessWindowHint window flag set for the translucency to work.`

Comment: @Devopia, setting Qt::FramelessWindowHint not showing anything for me

Comment: I tried with below code

Comment: setStyleSheet("background:transparent");
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
    setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    ui->setupUi(this);